# How to stop ubuntu desktop to connect to any ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, server

I have reduced all the listening services on my ubuntu desktop in order to not see the word LISTEN in netstat. While checking netstat today i saw a tcp_wait connection to port ubuntu-content-cache-3.ps5.canonical.com:80 while there was nothing open except a terminal. I know those are safe connections but i wish to make it stop. I need this desktop only for 1 application and nothing else bothering my paranoia.
System is running lxde with lightdm on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: So, would it be ok to connect to any other server, but ubuntu?

Comment: `ubuntu-content-cache-3.ps5.canonical.com:80` looks like a website. If so, then the solution is to Quit your web browser.

Comment: I am not using a browser, the connection was made by some ubuntu service running in background by default. I need the networking open but without any unwanted service running and connecting to the outside.